# The web application at [url] could not be found

Tags: search, wss-3.0, shared-service-provider, content-database

Any ideas on the error below?

This happens when I try to search for content on my WSS 3.0 site.

ERROR

" The web application at [url] could not be found. Verify that you have typed the url correctly. If the url should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need to add a new request url mapping to the intended application. "

Did I miss any step in configuring my search on central admin?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're sure that the web application does exist? ;-)

It's worth checking your Alternate Access Mappings to ensure that the URL that your Search is trying to use is set up.

I found [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jjameson/archive/2009/10/08/web-application-at-could-not-be-found-error-on-moss-2007-x64.aspx) that surmises that it might be a problem if you have an X86 component trying to access x64 MOSS.  Are you running 64 bit?  Are you sure that any web parts etc. are targeted to the correct environment?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple possibilities for above issue:

1. The URL does not exist on the farm.
2. the code is in a console or windows application which you are now running with an account that does not have permissions to connect to the SQL server
3. the code is in a console or windows application that is compiled with platform target x86, while your SharePoint server is x64.

More details on my blog: 
http://nileshmandekar.blogspot.com/2011/03/web-application-at-could-not-be-found.html

Answer (score 1):

Changing the Build PlatForm of my WPF App to x64 did the trick for me.
I have found this solution through one of the answers in the blog at following url: [link here](http://blog.sharepointrx.com/2009/08/26/the-web-application-at-url-could-not-be-found-verify-that-you-have-typed-the-url-correctly-if-the-url-should-be-serving-existing-content-the-system-administrator-may-need-to-add-a-new-request-url/#comment-716).

Answer (score 0):

First, run your code elevated: (open the Site inside  SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges())
Second, run the code as Site Coll. Admin (if a console app for example).

If after that you receive an error like:

> "Error: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx} failed due to the following error:
>   80040154, "

Rebuild your code to run explicitly on x64 processor.

Answer (score -2):

Right Click on Project  | Build | change Platform Target | x64 or AnyCpu